# journald is not following the configurations

Tags: linux, fedora, systemd

I'm using Fedora 22 which is now using `systemd`.

What bothers me currently is that the `journald` seems to be ignoring my configurations. Here's my `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.

```
[Journal]
Storage=persistent
Compress=yes
SystemMaxUse=128M
RuntimeMaxUse=64M
ForwardToSyslog=no
ForwardToKMsg=no
ForwardToConsole=no
ForwardToWall=no
```

I set `Storage=persistent` but I have to create `/var/log/journal` manually  and restart `systemd-journald` to enable logging. (Otherwise `journalctl` will show `no entries`.) This looks like the default `Storage=auto` setting but not mine.

I set `ForwardToWall=no` but I can still see a mass of logs in TTYs. This also looks like the default `ForwardToWall=yes`.

How can I make `journald` follow my custom configurations?

Comment: Silly maybe but I have to ask for: did you restart the service? `systemctl restart systemd-journald.service`

Comment: @Hastur Of course, I even rebooted my machine.

Comment: For decreasing amount of logs on your TTY see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/351402/238539)