# Error when shutdown Ubuntu 14.04 printk

Tags: ubuntu

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS version. It logs in correctly. However, I have found a flood of printk messages when I logout/shutdown the computer. See the error in the image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuWMp.jpg]

I have used the solution suggested in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console).

i.e., modify `sysctl.conf` file by UN-commenting `kernel.printk = 3 4 1 3`. But the system does not allow me to modify sysctl.conf.

I have used the techniques suggested in

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2mDGq5KqpA

as well as [this website](http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2619.page)

Both of them fail to modify the files.

Please note that I am using samsung ssd Pro drive and Dell desktop computer with default BIOS setup.