# How to mute kernel messages at startup in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, arch-linux

I am playing around with a custom Plymouth bootsplash in my Arch laptop. I have followed [this](http://www.archlinuxuser.com/2013/05/how-to-install-plymouth-on-archlinux.html) tutorial and everything went OK.

My problem is that, after selecting Arch on Grub (even when I only have Arch installed), a blinking cursor appears on the top left corner of my screen, makes my whole bootsplash blink and floods the screen with messages.

Is there a way to deal with it? Following [this](https://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console#351402) answer didn't work for me, as I `/etc/sysctl.conf` does not exist in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vt.global_cursor_default=0` (as a parameter) to the end of the GRUB kernel boot line for your Linux OS (the line that starts with `linux`).

That will hide the blinking cursor during boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot) wiki entry. Copying the following line into your /etc/default/grub will do the trick:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet loglevel=3 rd.systemd.show_status=auto rd.udev.log-priority=3 loglevel=0"
```

This is likely to appear in line 9, and you won't need to type again `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`. Note that `vga=current` didn't work for me, and although the wiki recommended it, it converted my bootsplash into an ugly gray screen with three dots, try it anyway in case it solved your problem.

Next, it is really important to add `loglevel=<level>`, where, citing the wiki,

> is any number between 0 and 7, where 0 is the most critical, and 7 is debug levels of printing.

This is what really solved my problem, as my screen didn't stop displaying level 3 and lower alerts. Changing it to 0 is the way to go if you don't want to be bothered unless your computer is in a real trouble... don't worry, you'll be notified instantly if any error makes your machine catch fire.

Comment: You can edit a grub boot line at startup too; might be worth trying this first before modifying grub config (don't forget to `sudo update-grub` to make changes active).