# Linux Redhat 7.1 UDP requests displaying in command line

Tags: linux, bash, firewall, redhat-enterprise-linux, udp

I'm unfamiliar with Linux server administration and I am trying to disable firewall log messages appearing in the console, the version of Linux is RedHat Enterprise 7.1. I would like to know a command to disable these messages:

The messages been received go along the lines of: (Making it harder to type commands):

Firewall: UDP Blocked In eth- Out=

These messages appear around every second.

Comment: This might help: [How to stop kernel messages from flooding my console?](http://superuser.com/q/351387/340330)

Answer (score 1):

These messages reflect the rejected traffic by `firewalld`, so to disable it, you have to turn off the debug level of denied packets.

To do this, choose one of the options below :

1. By **CLI**:

   ```
   firewall-cmd --set-log-denied=off
   ```
2. By editing **FIREWALLD** configuration file :

   ```
   vi /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf
   ```

Then, set `LogDenied=off`.
Note that both solutions are permanent.