# Why do dmesg firewall messages get printed to my zsh on openSuse?

Tags: linux, firewall, zsh, opensuse

I set up a VM running openSUSE Tumbleweed and changed the default shell to `zsh`. My AVM Fritzbox router regularly probes the VM on port 80 to check for webservices. Because port 80 is closed on the openSUSE system, the request gets blocked.

I also get a dmesg (?) message written to my current `zsh` prompt. That didn't seem to be the case with `bash`. What could be the reason and how do I stop the messages from appearing (besides opening port 80 of course).

Comment: What exactly does the message say?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski `[ 1018.144672] SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT IN=ens33 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:d0:ce:63:c8:0e:14:d2:4d:dc:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.1.54 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60930 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51668 DPT=80 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (020405B40402080A044A1C170000000001030305)` but I don't think that is going to help alot, since i already described its meaning.

Comment: Does it happen on `/dev/tty1` only? [This may help](https://superuser.com/q/351387/432690).

Comment: seems to be printed to the current tty, but not to ssh ptys. still you may be on to something with sysctl